# Error "System function unparsed-text#1 is not available with this host language"

Tags: xquery, saxon

I'm using Saxon to execute the following xquery;

```
fn:unparsed-text("text.txt")
```

But I'm getting the following error message;

```
javax.xml.xquery.XQException:
System function unparsed-text#1 is not available with this host language
```

What does that error message mean?

Comment: It means that it knows that function, but it is no aviable in XQuery. XQuery 3.0 would add this XSLT 2.0 function. But, do remember that XQuery/XPath/XSLT 3.0 are **Working Draft**, so don't use them jet in production enviroment. It's better to use an stable extension function. Even developing your own it shouldn't be so hard.

Comment: What's a "stable extension function"? Where can I get documentation to use it in saxon? I'm calling the saxon engine from java.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an explanation and suggested workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The [`unparsed-text()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-unparsed-text) function is an XSLT 2.0 - only function. It isn't an XPath 2.0 function**.

Hopefully, this may change in XPath 3.0.

Because you are using Saxon, you may try to use the saxon extension function **[`saxon:transform()`](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/extensions/functions/transform.xml)** and in the transformation invoke `unparsed-text()`.